# How to add Filezilla to the Linux Mint Panel?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, filezilla

How do you add Filezilla to the Linux Mint Panel if you know what directory it is installed, and it had currently a launcher on the desktop (Cinnamon)?

Comment: Right clic then add to panel

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Mint start menu by the system settings. Here you can add a binary path to it, and also specify its icon.

After it is the start menu, a right click on the menu element can put it to the panel.

Its desktop icon is here irrelevant, in the startmenu editor you can add a binary path and optionally specify an icon file.